# how to find out which version of asp my website is coded in

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, plesk

I have a website which is coded in asp. We have upgraded out plesk server from plesk 9 to 12 since then, I am getting a "Internal server error".

It could be that the new version of ASP installed on Plesk is not compatiable with the version of ASP that the website is coded in. Right now we do not have the website only the code, so is there a way to find out which version my ASP code is coded in just so that I can install an older version of ASP on my server to get the website back up and running?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be much more useful if you shared the actual exception that is raised. Look in the eventviewer of your server. As versions of asp.net are tied with the installed .NET framework you will not simply install an older version, at best those versions are already there. I bet you have a configuration error.

Comment: this is all i get when i load my website - www.chandco.net

Comment: ""Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: If you look in the event logs on the server, the Application Log should give you a more useful error, probably including the actual exception that was thrown by the code.

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox where do i find the events log as I'm new to ASP and plesk. Im actually a PHP developer. Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows Server, type eventvwr in the Start-Run dialog

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox - would this Application log be under the Windows Logs? I have loads of Errors!

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox ive got loads of information, warning and Error logs. What does that mean?

Comment: There will be one or more errors and/or warnings related to .Net that will have additional detail.  There will likely be a stack trace there as well.  That is the information that is needed to resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open your project in visual studio. once your project is loaded in visual studio click web config file in that you can find .Net framework version.